# laravel pass array see object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm stuck and probably missing something really obvious.. but..

I'm trying to pass an array of roles via jwt to my SPA (not a jwt question - that bit works fine)

I get my list of role names via

```
$roles = $this->roles->pluck('title')->toArray();
```

the roles function is

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
```

in laravel this works fine and logging $roles out I see ["Admin"]

on the SPA response, however, I see the entire roles object joined to the user object (the user object is supposed to be passed over here) eg:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Admin",
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "user_loggedin_state": null,
        "user_login_time": null,
        "user_login_hash": "",
        "user_log_out_time": null,
        "user_phone": "123456",
        "user_job": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "team_id": 1,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Admin",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "pivot": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "role_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I want is

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Admin",
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "user_loggedin_state": null,
        "user_login_time": null,
        "user_login_hash": "",
        "user_log_out_time": null,
        "user_phone": "123456",
        "user_job": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "team_id": 1,
        "roles": ["Admin"]
    }
}
```

I definitely pass the array to jwt, not the object - to validate this I wrapped the $roles in a function

```
public function rolesArray()
    {
        $roles = $this->roles->pluck('title')->toArray();
        Log::info($roles);
        return $roles;
    }
```

and the jwt fn

```
public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [
            'roles'             => $this->rolesArray(),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Why you are not using API Resources ?

Comment: If you are not used resources before tell me to explain more about that

Comment: well using API Resources isn't going to solve this problem I think.. because the issue is that even when I can see I am returning an array, somehow Laravel managed to return the full object

Comment: Ok, I`m writing an answer for you. hopefully, this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the bleeding obvious was that all this data is of course in the JWT payload..

I was confused since the moment I added stuff in the custom fields - Laravel sent the User object across in the response as well (which I want to find a way of stopping since its in the clear)

Answer (score 0):

Use API Resources for getting your own outputs.

Run this command to make a new resource for getting users:

```
php artisan make:resource UserListResource
```

In App/Http/Resourcers open UserListResource.php file

Change toArray method to:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'email_verified_at' => $this->email_verified_at,
        'user_loggedin_state' => $this->user_loggedin_state,
        'user_login_time' => $this->user_login_time,
        'user_login_hash' => $this->user_login_hash,
        'user_log_out_time' => $this->user_log_out_time,
        'user_phone' => $this->user_phone,
        'user_job' => $this->user_job,
        'create_dates' => [
            'created_at_human' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans(),
            'created_at' => $this->created_at
        ],
        'update_dates' => [
            'updated_at_human' => $this->updated_at->diffForHumans(),
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at
        ],
        'deleted_dates' => [
            'deleted_at_human' => $this->deleted_at->diffForHumans(),
            'deleted_at' => $this->deleted_at
        ],
        'team_id' => $this->team_id
        'roles' => new RolesShowResource($this->roles),
    ];
}
```

Then make Roles resources:

```
php artisan make:resource RolesShowResource
```

Open the RolesShowResource.php and do these changes:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'title' => $this->title,
    ];
}
```

So when you want to return objects try using the code below in fetching users:

```
return UserListResource::collection($users);
```